# Multiple row & column table data into string

Tags: php, html, sql

Im trying to make a datalist which will have the options as:

> ItemCode - Name

Code and Name are in the same table but are in different columns

Ive got it working for just code:

```
<?php 
  while($res=mysql_fetch_row($code))
   {
    $fullname=$res[0];
    echo "<option value=$fullname></option>";
   }
 ?>
```

I tried doing the following for both:

```
<?php 
 while(($res=mysql_fetch_row($code)) && ($res2=mysql_fetch_row($name)))
 {
   $fullname=$res[0]." - ".$res2[0];
   echo "<option value=$fullname></option>";
 }
?>
```

However I had no joy, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps try to debug what is inside your $res array - i.e. var_dump($res). What you probably want is something like $res['1'] . '-' . $res['2']

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "<option value=$fullname>$fullname</option>";
//instead of $module?
```

Comment: Apologies, that was me missing one when I changed the names of the variables from the originals.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php
$query="select ItemCode,Name from tablename";
$result=mysql_query($query);

$cols=2;        
echo "<table>";
do{
    echo "<tr>";
    for($i=1;$i<=$cols;$i++)
    {   $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
        ?>
             <td>
                 <table>
                  <tr valign="top">

                    <td>
                    <b><?=$row['ItemCode'] ?></b><br />
                    <?=$row['Name'] ?><br />

                    </td>
                    <td width="50">&nbsp;</td>  <!-- Create gap between columns -->
                     </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
            <?
    }
} while($row);
echo "</table>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use something like this:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $value = $row['item_code'] . " - " . $row['name'];
    echo '<option value="' . $value . '">' . $value . '</option>';
}
```

Note: mysql_query, mysql_fetch_row and mysql_fetch_assoc are deprecated, use something else.

> This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.